# OpenLDAP: interpreting username@domainname as uid=username,ou=domainname

Tags: authentication, openldap

Is that possible to tweak some settings that would make OpenLDAP always interpreting `uid=username@domainname` as `uid=username,ou=domainname` in authentication queries?

Of course, making the clients to do this job would be a much more ecological way, but this would be a less preferable option in my case.